# What Google Developer Console services is Free to use?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) in my app and I found that I need developer console.

I found this : https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

On this site it says that I need to pay $25 to register but on Android Developers site I found another link [https://console.developers.google.com/project?utm_referrer=http:%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fgoogle%2Fgcm%2Fgs.html](https://console.developers.google.com/project?utm_referrer=http%3a%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fgoogle%2Fgcm%2Fgs.html)

Is this one free for GCM or I still need to pay $25 ?

Comment: `C2DM` or `GCM` always free check on official [DOCS](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Cloud Messaging for Android is free and unlimited. You just need to use your Google/gmail id to log in and see the list of APIs and details of each. You can also enable specific APIs from there.
See the following link ,
[Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~avenchodk/apiui/api)

You will need to pay $25 when you want to sign up as a publisher. So when you yourself want to publish your apps to Google Play , then only you have to pay.

Comment: @Yvette The terms and conditions may have changed but, Google Cloud Messaging is completely free no matter how big your messaging needs are, and there are no quotas. Refer: https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/messaging/

Comment: I find the question has been closed as off-topic but the answer simply answers it and it seems to be useful for at least 6 people. If the answer has no place on SO, the comments have no place too. I believe the right approach for that would be deleting the question rather.